# multi touch events to mouse events for java application

Tags: mt4j

I have a rich complex Java Swing Application. I would like the multi touch events to be converted into Mouse events for the Swing Applications.

Is there a way to do it without changing significantly the existing Java Application ?

Comment: can you clarify your question please. what multi touch events? are you using a multi touch display? you have a mt4j tag which means your are using mt4j?

Answer (score 1):

When I did something that sounds similar to what you're asking, I ended up using the java.awt.Robot class to create mouse clicks according to the touch notifications. I was not using mt4j, though, but rather a proprietary multitouch screen's API that wasn't especially mature.